# Baby born in UK. Can it travel to the USA on a British passport before getting a USA passport/SSN?

Tags: us-citizens, uk-citizens

The baby's father is American, the mother is British. We are supposed to be travelling in a couple of weeks, and do not have time to wait for the US consulate appointment and application for a passport, which takes another month. The British passport process is faster.

Is it possible to apply for a US passport/SSN once we are back in the States? Even if the baby arrived on a British passport with ESTA?

Comment: US citizens -- including infants -- need to enter on a US passport. You can't get a ESTA as (or on behalf of) a US citizen.

Comment: Your husband should read this link https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/while-abroad/birth-abroad.html and if your child is a US citizen they need a US passport to enter the country.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas what the law says and what is possible are rather different.  I've read about people coming to the US without a US passport for their child, and they reported that it was fairly painless, though I don't remember whether the stories took place before or after the implementation of ESTA.

Comment: Related: [Child who entered under ESTA/VWP accompanying US citizen mother](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/93980/19400).

Comment: @Newton apparently 8 USC 1185(b) is not necessarily strictly enforced; this presumably because doing so would interfere with a citizen's inherent right to enter the country.  For anyone who shows up at the border without a passport (or acceptable substitute, where applicable), the immigration officer waives the requirement and allows the person to enter.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, all the comments have been really helpful. We are going to delay our flight back to the States until the US passport comes through